# Summing a Column values Starting with the Last one in Matlab

Tags: matlab

is there a function in matlab that sums up values starting from the last row and susbstitue the next row with summed values? for example:

```
data=     1          result  21
          2                  20  
          3                  18 
          4                  15
          5                  11  
          6                   6
```

Comment: I think you should look at `cumsum` http://uk.mathworks.com/help/matlab/ref/cumsum.html#btrgrnv-2_1 In fact cumsum(flipud(data)) should do it.

Comment: @GameOfThrows you should make an answer out of that, as it is exactly what he wants (don't forget the second `flipud` though, to revert the result: `flipud(cumsum(flipud(data)))`)

Answer (score 2, accepted):

GameOfThrows is on the right track, but you need an additional `flipud` when you're done:

```
out = flipud(cumsum(flipud(data)));
```

The first flip ensures that we start summing from the last element instead of the first.  We then perform our cumulative sum but you also want to be sure that the order is reversed so you have to call `flipud` one more time.   However, to be absolutely safe, because we don't know if your data is a row or column vector, I'm going to ensure that your data is a column vector before doing what you ask:

```
out = flipud(cumsum(flipud(data(:))));
```

Comment: Or use direction in `cumsum(___,direction)`? Not tested though.

Comment: @Divakar Tried that. The second parameter only specifies the dimension... I wish it worked for direction too.

Comment: yeah i was just reading about the command suggested by GameOfThrows  but adding the flipud suggested by rayryeng just did the work. Thanx

Comment: @rayryeng The **third** input is the direction, not the second. So specifying dimension and direction should work! So: `cumsum(data(:),1,'reverse')` - but attention: this behaviour got introduced with Matlab R2014b!

Comment: @thewaywewalk my `help cumsum` did not tell me that which is why I didn't see the direction. My PC is using R2014a... so that makes sense!